# Paging Toolbar Store Reconfigure?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

On an ExtJS grid, you can use `reconfigure` to programmatically change the store of the grid. Is there an equivalent for the paging toolbar?

I've looked through the ExtJS docs several times for the paging toolbar and there doesn't seem to be a reconfigure or a setStore function, and there isn't even a store property to set.

This is ExtJS 4 by the way.

Comment: any component that mixes in Bindable will have a bindStore() method. This includes grids, pagers, comboboxes, dataviews.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Ext.toolbar.Paging` has mixin `Ext.util.Bindable`. So, you just can to call `bindStore` method, and ExtJS 4.1 will do all other work itself. For example, I've edited paging.js in examples/grid folder, and add to grid following toolbar:

```
    tbar: [{
        text: 'switch to store 2',
        handler: function() {
            pager.bindStore(store2);
            grid.reconfigure(store2);
            store2.loadPage(1);
        }
    }]
```

It's all you need to do. You can see [online demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/guyfawkes/vwbwQ/).

Comment: Is that something new in 4.1 or is that in everything since 4.0? I'm using 4.0.7 to be extra clear.

Comment: In ExtJS 4 (4.0.7, for example) Ext.toolbar.Paging hasn't mixin Ext.util.Bindable, but has **own** method bindStore which do the same work.

@sra, my code works perfectly. Please, give me a proof it doesn't works.

Comment: I verified that it works in my code. `bindStore` was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @GuyFawkes.

It's a little frustrating that depending on the component, tying a store to the component has a different function name. `Reconfigure`, `bindStore`, `setStore`, etc. ExtJS seems to have quite a bit of inconsistency.

Comment: Yeah, you need to read ext-all-debug.js all time you work with ExtJS :) Good luck!